# mysql password not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reset mysql root password ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password)

I executed the query

```
UPDATE mysql.users set password= PASSWORD('123456') WHERE users='root' and host='localhost';
flush priviledges;
```

and after this mysql is not running. phpmyadmin and mysql console both are not working

> `#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo here:

```
flush priviledges;
```

should be

```
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [reset the root password for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Comment: i created the txt file and saved in c: and than from cmd i am executing the following command
C:\>C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\bin\mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
still its not giving any kind of output..