# mysql in ubuntu login problems

Tags: mysql, authentication

Working with mysql in ubuntu I need to make some changes, but I cannot figure out what my login credentials are. I have searched high and low for any information leading to what i set the username and password to be. Is there anyway i can find this info or do i need to "blow it away" and start from scratch or ... ? Im really confused.

When I type in mysql -u root -p to use a password none of mine work nor does a blank pass word or mysql -u root. Now when I try my computers user name that does work either mysql -u gavin -p.

Any idea, please let me know!

Comment: Take a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password

Answer (score 2):

Unless you remember it, there will be no way for you to retrieve it. You need to reset it.

You should read [Resetting the Root Password: Unix Systems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix) from the documentation. This will help you reset your root password.