# MySQL/phpMyAdmin Reset ROOT PASSWORD?

Tags: mysql, linux, passwords, root

I'm having MySQL on RHEL, and phpMyAdmin interface also. I have normal MySQL user access which i remember but i forget the `root` password.

- How to SAFELY reset the MySQL `root` password? (I have `root` account on O/S)

Comment: This is answered on serverfault.com : "Lost MySQL password" - http://serverfault.com/questions/287225/lost-mysql-password/287235#287235

Comment: There're also several dupes heres, I've chosen [a random one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Stop mysqld and restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges. Because this is insecure, you might want to use --skip-grant-tables in conjunction with --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting.

Connect to the mysqld server with this command:

```
shell> mysql
```

Issue the following statements in the mysql client. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
    ->                   WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change

Comment: In the page, it is saying to stop the service by `pid`. Is it the same as `service mysqld stop` ??? Why using `pid` ?

Comment: +1 but it requires editing the .pid file (as described in the link)

Comment: So does it mean, `service mysql stop` won't release the `.pid` file??

Comment: If you read the section towards the bottom of the page (posted above) you'll see you dont need the pid.

Comment: if you are confused about how to set `--skip-grant-tables` option then please refer my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/24888261/1924296

Answer (score 0):

**WINDOWS USERS**

For me in wondows 8 this worked;
First go to where you installed mysql, I was using wamserver and installed it under `D:\Programs\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin` so `cd` to that directory, then;

```
-> mysql UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('xvpaic7q') -> WHERE User='root'

-> FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```