# How to find password in mysql in mac os?

Tags: java, mysql, macos

I installed mysql and set password  but now I forgot password.
please suggest me how to get/retrieve or reset password.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about circumventing mysql security.

Comment: Un-install and re-install it?

Comment: I removed from mac and reinstalled. then also I am getting the same requirement of password

Comment: Well if that's a problem then you must be using this database somehow in you code, hence having the password written somewhere... no ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset mysql root password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password)

Comment: thanks for reply. I not written password anywhere

Answer (score 2):

According to your question I guess you're the administrator of that computer, i.e. you lost root password for mysql.
If this is true, you should be able to set a new password for your mysql as follow.

First stop mysql and log-in it skipping authentication:

```
$ sudo mysqladmin shutdown
$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

As --skip-gran-tables enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges, we want to use --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting. Thus reducing risks for your data.

Now let's update the password:

```
$ mysql
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('store_in_a_safe_place') WHERE user='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;
$ sudo mysqladmin shutdown
$ sudo mysqld &
```

The FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change.

Now you can use your new password.

If you forgot the password for another user, simply login as root and follow the steps above, replacing 'root' with the correct username.

You can read more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose for a moment that this is possible. This means that you (or everyone else) can find password for any mysql running in the world and (unless other security tools stop him) access the data stored there.

I hope this answers your question. I am sorry for sarcasm.

**EDIT**

After the sarcastic comment I can give you a practical advice. If you do not have any data there just re-install it (as it was already mentioned by several guys). 
If you have data that you want to preserve do the following.

1. Backup your data first.
2. Re-install database. This time remember (or write down) the password.
3. Create schemas again.
4. Copy your data files on the just created files.

I hope this will work. Please follow this link to get to find location of your data files: http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/where-does-mysql-stored-the-data-in-my-harddisk/

Comment: +1, *Reductio ad absurdum* often can appear as sarcasm but this is the only sensible answer.

Comment: I like your comment. Thanks for the short Latin language lesson :)

Comment: thanks for reply...  I removed mysql from mac and reinstalled but getting the same problem of password.

Comment: Wait, did mysql setup program ask you the password?

Comment: after this command it ask for password.                                 sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root