# mysql, get superadmin password and user name

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to work with a site where they don't remember the super admin password and user name. I can access to the database but with a no full access account.

If I have access to all the files in php my admin, can I get the password and the user name of the super admin?

Comment: Posible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how much access to the MySQL services on the server you can get. Try looking up "How to Reset MySQL Root password."

Answer (score 0):

On top of what Tony Arnold said, you should be able to find the super admin pass within the MySQL database (of course depending on the database as stated above) this might help you:

https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F#Method_1:_configuration.php_file