# LAMP forget password of user root in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, fedora

I have install LAMP in fedora 22 maybe 2 month ago, and I never use it. but when I start to use it, I forgot root password in phpMyAdmin, I try many way ,research and practice but it's not work. when I log to user root by command

```
mysql -u root
```

it's displayed

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

have any solution to solve this problem. thank you in advance

Comment: This is less to do about phpmyadmin than it is about mysql. [Here's a great resource to resetting the mysql root password in fedora](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password)

Comment: nice tutorial , I am try to practice this tutorial, but I fail to log to use root "mysql -uroot" I got some error " ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset mysql root password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password)