# Reset MySQL 8.0 password on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8 version for a long time but now I forget the MySQL root user password. How can I reset the password? I followed a lot of articles on the web, but nothing worked.

I tried commands:

1. `mysqld_safe -skip-grant-tables &`
2. `mysqld --init-file=/mysql-init &`

But did not work for me.

Comment: Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset mysql root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password)

Answer (score 0):

create file `mysql-preset.sql` and insert the below command in it:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

**Caution** Before going further stop your mysql instance. Make sure that it is not working

```
kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`
```

or

```
service mysqld stop
```

then start mysql instance with the command below to change password.

```
mysqld --init-file=mysql-preset.sql  &
```

Comment: Are you sure about that answer? I don't think `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin` is available on CentOS

Comment: I didnt see centos tag.

Comment: I rephrased my statement.

Comment: you must be doing something wrong.. see the official documentation, This answer is summarized using official doc.  see:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html