# Mysql automatically starts and stops when installed via brew

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I have installed mysql@5.7 via brew. When i run brew services list then sometimes it says started some time it says stopped.
[image]

When i try to do mysql -u root then it says

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'aakarshit'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: The error tells you that your attempt to connect was actively refused. You will need to look into the reason. Quite possibly you need to provide a proper password.

Comment: Because you are not giving a password! Do you know the password for the aakarshit user?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i know the password

Comment: @RiggsFolly aakarshit@VYMO-IT-LPT-712 ~ % mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Are you trying to use the `root` user account or the `aakarshit` account?

Comment: To use the `root` account you need the password for the root account

Comment: @RiggsFolly how do i set the passsword for root account?

Comment: Well are you the owner of this MySQL install? If you are and you installed MySQL did you set a password when you did the install?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I installed via brew,
brew install mysql@5.7

Comment: If you didnt set a `root` password then do `mysql -uroot -p` and when asked for a password, just hit the Enter key to indicate there is no password set

Comment: @RiggsFolly aakarshit@VYMO-IT-LPT-712 ~ % mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
aakarshit@VYMO-IT-LPT-712 ~ %

Comment: So it looks like there is a password on the `root` account. So if you dont know it you may have to reset it, try some of these suggestions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258124/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password